# How to open internal frame from another internal frame in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created an internal frame in main frame and I want to open another internal frame from the old one.

I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions?

I tried many a few different ways to open another internal frame:

- I used setVisible(true) method but it does not work.
- I created object of mainFrame but did not get the correct method.

I googled for it and searched Stack Overflow but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could start with the Java tutorial [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

But a possible process could be something like

```
JInternalFrame newFrame = JInternalFrame();
newFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
newFrame.setVisible(true);
getParent().add(newFame); // assuming our current class is a JInternalFrame on a JDeskTop
```

Comment: sir i tried this code but it did not work. I created an internal frame. On it i created a button. There is one more internal frame. when i click on button i want to open the another one internal frame. On button click i wrote the method which you told me but i did not work.

Comment: Drop us some sample code, including the container you are trying to add to - I suspect your either not using a JDesktopPane or a LayoutManager is getting involved

Comment: Don't forget to `pack()`. :-)

Comment: @CatalinaIsland while I agree, in the normal course of events, pack is a good idea, but it coud result in a frame whose size is 0x0, virtually hiding the frame

Comment: sir when i put **CurrentFrame.SetVisible(false)** then above is working. finally i found the solution
**thank You** for you Guid.

Comment: @PradeepBhati rather the hiding the current from try newFrame.moveToFront() - see if that helps, otherwise, stick with your solution

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this :

```
public class InternalFrameDemo extends JFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    JDesktopPane desktop;

    public InternalFrameDemo() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");
        final int inset = 50;
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset, screenSize.width - inset * 2, screenSize.height - inset * 2);

        // Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); // a specialized layered pane
        createFrame(); // create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);
    }

    protected void createFrame() {
        final JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Document #" + ++openFrameCount);
        frame.setLocation(xOffset * openFrameCount, yOffset * openFrameCount);
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton());
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (final java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        return new JButton(new AbstractAction("New") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                createFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        final InternalFrameDemo frame = new InternalFrameDemo();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adaptation of [InternalFrameDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/InternalFrameDemoProject/src/components/InternalFrameDemo.java)